# Do these two complexities belong in the same theta class?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

[image]

> Do $n\log_d(n)$ and $n\log(n)$ lie in the same theta class?

Comment: Thank you for all the edits you made to improving my question!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, due to the identity $\log_b x=\dfrac{\log_a x}{\log_a b}$ (for $a,b\in\Bbb R^+\setminus\{1\},\ x\in\Bbb R^+$).